# Prevent Call Statements From Running At The Same Time - Batch

Tags: batch-file, call, sequence

I am using a .bat file to open up multiple windows for a program to expedite software installation and computer setup. The result I am looking for is that when I click the "X" to close out of one window, I want the next call statement to execute and open the next statement on the list. This works fine when the call statements have the same filetype. Example:

```
@echo off
call "New Text Document.txt"
call "New Text Document (3).txt"
@pause
```

But let's say I add a statement that calls a web browser in between my two text file calls.:

```
@echo off
call "New Text Document.txt"
call "a.url"
call "New Text Document (3).txt"
@pause
```

Now is when I experience the issue. When I close my first text file it will open up "a.url" and "New Text Document (3).txt" at the same time instead of one sequentially after I close out of one of them like it does when I just have two text files.

I understand that if I put  `@pause` in between my call statements I won't have this problem and it would still speed up the software/setting setup process greatly, but I would really like to have it open things sequentially after closing a window instead. What can I do to resolve this?

Thanks in advance for all help offered.

Comment: I'm not sure why you voted my question down, they will work. Please adjust your marking so I can earn my rating back, as I'm trying to be able to comment to help people. You need to have those files in the same path as the .bat file that you create.

Comment: OK, I see. This might be the problem. By calling "New Text Document.txt" you actually start call the standard program to open txt files. Have you tried to call the actual program with parameters? E.g. notapad.exe "<path to the txt file>" or yourbrowser.exe "<URL>" etc.? Btw.: I can't remove the downvote because it's not mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace your `call` commands with `start`

```
start "" /wait "new document.txt"
start "" /wait cmd /c "something.cmd"
start "" /wait calc.exe
```

Comment: This could help but why start "" /wait "..." and not start /wait "..."

Comment: This was a clever idea that I didn't know about, but it still doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @MichaelS, just to follow the same order in the `start /?`

Comment: @Brad, how does it not work? in what cases/programs does it fail?

Comment: What I did was I copied the code that you suggested I try, but I changed the file names to match what I want to open (given in my question). I also tried switching the /wait around like @MichaelS had mentioned. It opens the first text file fine, then I click the "X" to close it and begin the next start statement. The next two things to open are my .url and my .txt. Since they are different file types it still opens them at the same time. Instead of waiting like intended. Will it work for you?

Comment: MC ND: You don't need the "" right after the start command. start /wait program.exe is enough. @Brad: Does the problem only occur when you open a URL? I've tested it with a mix of notepad and calc and it worked fine but it didn't work with a browser.

Comment: @MichaelS, `start` command has a curious behaviour, the first quoted argument is considered the title of the window, so, to prevent problems with quoted paths, the `""` is a good practice

Comment: @Brad, the `/wait` parameter waits for the launched process, but in the case of the urls the launched process spawns an browser instance and exits, so, the started process has ended and the batch continues. Try something like `start "" /wait "c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://www.google.com"`